Integer values being converted to float after being passed into a JSON file
I'm having a problem I've never before experienced with Karate. This is the basic skeleton of the code I'm working with right now:
Feature: This is a feature to test account updation

Scenario: Scenario 1
    # code...

Scenario: Scenario 2
    # code...

Scenario: Scenario 3

    # This feature-file is a prerequisite helper file shared by scenarios 1, 2 and 3
    # code fails here...
    * def updateAccount = call read('../../update-account-prerequisite.feature')

    # Rest of the code here...

This is the pre-requisite feature:
Scenario: Pre-req
    # some code here...
    * def accountId = response.id

    * def postString = read('post-payload.json')
    # Where scenario 3 fails
    * def updateSomething = call read('update-something.feature')

Whenever I execute the entire testsuite, scenario 3 alone fails each and every single time. Upon closer inspection, I found that it was due to an error in the update-account feature shared by all 3 scenarios. Somehow, when it reaches this line while executing scenario 3:
    * def postString = read('post-payload.json')

The accountId is converted to a float, and my test fails due to the invalid data type. When I try to execute scenario 3 alone, it passes. I tried many methods to do a force convert to integer.
None of those worked, and in the end the only thing that worked was directly putting the ~~ prefix directly in the JSON file to do a force convert. I was fine with this workaround and the code worked correctly.
Now, when I try to execute the code by removing the ~~ prefix in the JSON file, the code runs just fine! No issues whatsoever. I did not modify the rest of the code at all!
Why did my code behave that way in the first place? How can I make sure the same error doesn't come back?
A sample of how I'm passing data to my JSON file for reference:
{
    "name": "#(accountName)",
    "id": "#(accountId)",
    "additionalConfig": null,
}

Before it got passed into the JSON, accountId would have a value of say, 5. But in the payload of my request, accountId would take a value of 5.0
Using this worked to force convert id into an integer: "#(~~accountId)"

I'm confused, JSON doesn't support operators so unless you're throwing ~~ in a string, I don't see how that would do anything. Second, all numbers in JSON are floats thanks to JavaScript's runtime model; the fact that some environments allow them to be interpreted as integers (or even arbitrary-precision integers) is an extension. If you're passing around numbers with more than ~15 digits of significant precision, you should use JSON strings instead of numbers.

Yes, I'm throwing ~~ in a string. Sorry, for the unclear wording. Also, I'm passing numbers with 2 significant digits at max. What I wanted to know is it is actually an issue in my code or the way JSON numbers are represented

Please include some samples of the JSON so it's clearer what you're doing and how the data is stored.

I've added the JSON file
